# Parameters on linprog

Tags: scipy

Can anyone explain how the parameter bounds actuallly works. I am reading the doc and I am not able to understand it . 
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.linprog-simplex.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you ask for as the docs describe it exactly. But here is some example:

```
from scipy.optimize import linprog
c = [-1, 4]
A = [[-3, 1], [1, 2]]
b = [6, 4]
```

**No explicit bounds**: 
Default-behaviour; same for each variable

```
res = linprog(c, A, b)
# Default: lower-bound of each variable is 0, upper-bound is +inf
```

**Pair of explicit bounds**:
One bound-definition for all variables

```
x0_bnds = (-3, 5)
res = linprog(c, A, b, bounds=x0_bnds)
# lower-bound of each -3, upper-bound 5

x1_bnds = (-3, None)
res = linprog(c, A, b, bounds=x1_bnds)
# lower-bound of each -3, upper-bound +inf

x2_bnds = (-np.inf, None)
res = linprog(c, A, b, bounds=x2_bnds)
# lower-bound of each -inf, upper-bound +inf
```

**Sequence of pairs as explicits bounds**:
One bound-definition for each variable

```
x0_bnds = (None, None)
x1_bnds = (-3, None)
res = linprog(c, A, b, bounds=(x0_bnds, x1_bnds))
# x0 between 0 and +inf
# x1 between -3, +inf
# len(bounds) = len((x0_bnds, x1_bnds)) needs to be equal to number of vars
```

Comment: Thank you sascha , I am new in this field and any help is highly appreciated :)